# Distinguished triangle induced by short exact sequence

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I'm reading about derived categories of abelian categories from Huybrecht's book *Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry*. I'm having a lot of trouble with one of the exercises. In fact, at this point, I'm confident that the result is false.

> **Claim 1** (Huybrechts Exercise 2.27): Suppose $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is a short exact sequence
>   in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Then embedding this into the homotopy
>   $K(\mathcal{A})$ (as complexes supported in degree zero), we get a
>   distinguished triangle $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$.

My question is pretty much a repeat of [Short exact sequence makes exact triangle in derived category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331480/short-exact-sequence-makes-exact-triangle-in-derived-category), but there is no real answer there.

Based on answers and comments in [short exact sequences of complexes and triangles in the homotopy category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326960/short-exact-sequences-of-complexes-and-triangles-in-the-homotopy-category) and especially [A short exact sequence that cannot be made into an exact triangle. (Weibel 10.1.2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738348/a-short-exact-sequence-that-cannot-be-made-into-an-exact-triangle-weibel-10-1?rq=1), it seems like Huybrechts has made a false claim. It seems like the right way to modify this is:

> **Claim 2**: Suppose $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is a short exact sequence
>   in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Then embedding this into the derived category
>   $D(\mathcal{A})$ (as complexes supported in degree zero), we get a
>   distinguished triangle $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$.

Another thing it seems like people are implying in the threads I mentioned is that this is actually a specific instance of the following more general statement.

> **Claim 3**: Suppose $0 \to A^\bullet \to B^\bullet \to C^\bullet \to 0$ is a short exact sequence
>   in the chain complex category $\operatorname{Kom}(\mathcal{A})$. Then viewing this in the derived category
>   $D(\mathcal{A})$ as $A^\bullet \to B^\bullet \to C^\bullet \to A^\bullet[1]$, it is a
>   distinguished triangle.

**My questions are:** Am I correct that Claim 1 is false? Am I correct that Claims 2 and 3 are true? Can someone provide details on how to prove Claims 2 and/or 3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Claim 1 is indeed wrong : the short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z/2Z}\to\mathbb{Z/4Z}\to\mathbb{Z/2Z}\to 0$ does not define a distinguished triangle in the homotopy category. Indeed by definition a triangle $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$ is distinguished iff it is isomorphic to a triangle $A\to B\to\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)\to A[1]$, but $C=\operatorname{Cone}(\mathbb{Z/2Z\to Z/4Z})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ is the homotopy category.

To see this, note that if you have an isomorphism  $C\simeq \mathbb{Z/2Z}$ it will have to be represented by a morphism of complexes $\mathbb{Z/2Z}\to C$ (this is because $Hom_K=Hom_C/\sim_{htp}$), in other words, there will be a morphism of complexes :
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z/2Z}@>>>0\\
@.@VVV@VVV@.\\
0@>>>\mathbb{Z/2Z}@>>>\mathbb{Z/4Z}@>>>0
\end{CD}$$

which is an isomorphism in the homotopy category.

This is easy so see that there is only two such morphisms. But none of them are a homotopy equivalence : in fact they are not even a quasi-isomorphism !

---

This argument fail in the derived category because morphisms $\mathbb{Z/2Z}\to C$ does not necessarily comes from a morphism of complexes. We have in fact $$Hom_D(\mathbb{Z/2Z},C)=Hom_D(P,C)=Hom_K(P,C)=Hom_C(P,C)/\sim_{htp}$$
where $P$ is any projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.

Take your favorite resolution of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ (for example $P=\mathbb{Z\overset{\times 2}\to Z}$), you will see that there is a quasi-isomorphism $P\to C$. Even more : there is also a morphism $P\to\mathbb{Z/2Z}[1]$ leading to a triangle :
$$\mathbb{Z/2Z\to Z/4Z}\to P\to\mathbb{Z/2Z}[1]$$
which is isomorphic in the derived category to $\mathbb{Z/2Z\to Z/4Z}\to C\to\mathbb{Z/2Z}[1]$.

---

Claim 2 and Claim 3 are true but require a precision. Claim 2 follows from Claim 3, so let's have a look at Claim 3.

The correct claim is the following : if you have a short exact sequence of complexes $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, then there is a map $C\to A[1]$ in the derived category such that $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$ is a distinguished triangle.

In particular :

- this is not true for any map $C\to A[1]$
- the map $C\to A[1]$ only lives in the derived category and not necessarily at the level of complexes (as you can see by taking a short exact sequence of complexes concentrated in a single degree as above).

From your linked thread ([Short exact sequence makes exact triangle in derived category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331480/short-exact-sequence-makes-exact-triangle-in-derived-category?noredirect=1&lq=1)) you know that there is a quasi-isomorphism $\varphi:\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)\to C$.

So the map $C\to A[1]$ is constructed as : take the inverse of $\varphi$, that is $\varphi^{-1}:C\to\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)$ and compose with $\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)\to A[1]$.

(Note however that $\varphi^{-1}$ only exists in the derived category.)

With this construction of $C\to A[1]$, the claim is now obvious since by construction :
$$\begin{CD}
A@>f>> B@>i>>\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)@>p>> A[1]\\
@|@|@V\varphi VV@|\\
A@>f>> B@>g>> C@>p\circ \varphi^{-1}>> A[1]
\end{CD}$$
commutes and so is an isomorphism of triangles in the derived category.

Comment: I took the example of the linked thread, but an even easier short exact sequence which is not a distinguished triangle in the homotopy category is $$0\to\mathbb{Z\to Z \to Z/2Z}\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks for the extremely thorough answer. Can you say a bit more about the quasi-isomorphism $\varphi$? Is it basically projection onto the $B$ components? How do I see that it is a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: I mean, is $\varphi$ projection onto the $B$ components followed by $B \to C$.

Comment: There is no map $\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)\to B$ (the natural map goes the other way). But yes, on each degree take $\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)^n=B^n\oplus A^{n+1}\to B^n\to C^n$ and note that this defines a morphism of complexes (that is : it is compatible with the differentials). This also shows that $g=\varphi\circ i$ (the middle square of the last diagram commutes)

Comment: That makes sense. Why is $\varphi$ a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: Did you try to prove it using the hint in the linked thread ? Use that the mapping cone of an isomorphism has zero homology.

Comment: I don't know what hint you're referring to. Furthermore, $A \to B$ is not necessarily an isomorphism, so I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: The hint was to prove that $0\to \operatorname{Cone}(i)\to\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)\to C\to 0$ is exact where $i$ is the isomorphism $A\simeq i(A)$ (the image of $A$ in $B$). You have $\operatorname{Cone}(i)$ quasi-isomorphic to $0$ so $\operatorname{Cone}(A\to B)$ quasi-isomorphic to $C$.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. But could you elaborate more on the example $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow P \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[1].$$ I'm confused at how to construct the morphism $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow P$? It seems that the only plausible way is to make it a zero map. But if we put it as a zero map, how to construct a morphism of *triangles* from that triangle to $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow C \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[1].$$ ...

Comment: ... because the quasi-isomorphism $P \rightarrow C$ does not fit into a morphism of triangles. Thank you so much for your inspiring answer!

Comment: @HetongXu If you want to construct a map $\mathbb{Z/4Z}\to P$, you will need to take a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z/4Z}$.

Comment: @Roland Aha, thank you! (I hadn't realized the difference between maps in the category of chain complexes and maps in the derived category *again*. :(  )