# Distinguished triangle made me conclude $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$ (?) in derived category

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ be the exact sequence of complex $ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2  \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$,
and let $0 \to A' \to B' \to C' \to 0$ be another exact sequence of complex $ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2  \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$.
(Each object is the complex padded with zeros in both directions.)

I have learned every such short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ can be embedded to distinguished triangle $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ in the derived category.
([Distinguished triangle induced by short exact sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709625/distinguished-triangle-induced-by-short-exact-sequence), Claim 2 or 3)

Then, I have following commutative diagram between two distinguished triangle (in the derived category):
$$
%
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
C[-1]=0 & \ra{} & A=\mathbb{Z}/2 & \ra{(1,0)} & B=\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 & \ra{(0,1)} & C=\mathbb{Z}/2 \\
\da{id} & & \da{id} & &  & & \da{id} \\
C'[-1]=0 & \ra{} &  A'=\mathbb{Z}/2 & \ra{\times 2} & B'=\mathbb{Z}/4 & \ra{1} & C'=\mathbb{Z}/2\\
\end{array}
$$

By the axiom of triangulated category, I can insert a morphism $B \to B'$ here, and moreover by triangulated five lemma ([13.4.3 in stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014A)), it is isomorphism.

But $B$ and $B'$ apparently have different homology and seem to be never isomorphic.
So, what am I missing?

---

**EDIT** (response to comments)

(1) I fixed $\otimes$ into $\oplus$.

(2) I am aware that $B \to B'$ is a morphism in derived category, concretely something like $B \leftarrow X \to B'$ where these arrows are quasi-isomorphisms of complexes. But it still seems to be impossible to have such quasi-isomorphisms. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Is your $\otimes$ supposed to be an $\oplus$?

Comment: Isn't your question is answered in the very same post you link? The triangle that your second SEC defines is not given on the nose by that SEC (by the counterexample to the first incorrect *Claim 1*)? The detail given in there to *Claim 2* even explains that you have to be much more careful (and cannot work at the level of morphisms of complexes, but at the level of morphisms in the derived category).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you for your comment, but I cannot see the point. All objects in my two triangles are meant to be already embedded into the derive category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object $C[-1]$ is not zero; it is a complex having $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $-1$ and $0$ in all the other degrees.
The two morphisms $C[-1]\to A$ in the diagram are different (they correspond to two different elements of $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$), so the left square does not commute.
The point is that although there is no non-trivial morphism of complexes from $C[-1]$ to $A$, there are non-trivial morphisms from $C[-1]$ to $A$ **in the derived category**.

Comment: Is there any way to explain (to the OP) that this must be a manifestation of the fact that $\mathbb Z/4$ is represented by a non-trivial class in $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb Z/2,\mathbb Z/2)$ (which should be the map $C[-1] \to A$ in the der. cat. you refer to!)?

Comment: In general, the morphism $C\to A[1]$ arising from an exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, viewed as an element of $\mathrm{Ext}^1(C,A)$, coincides with the class representing the original extension. Therefore $C\to A[1]$ vanishes if and only if the extension splits. See Definition 13.27.4 and Lemma 13.27.5 of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XP.